# How to get users which were online everyday last week?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Data example:

```
id  visiting_time
1   13.01.2001 02:34
1   14.01.2001 02:36
1   15.01.2001 02:36
1   16.01.2001 02:37
1   17.01.2001 02:38
1   18.01.2001 02:39
1   19.01.2001 02:40
2   13.01.2001 02:35
2   15.01.2001 02:36
2   16.01.2001 02:37
2   17.01.2001 02:38
2   18.01.2001 02:39
2   19.01.2001 02:40
```

I want to get all users which were online everyday for the last week, f.e. from 13th january 00:00 till 20th january 00:00. 
For my data sample the answer is:

```
id
1
```

Comment: How do you define last week? Compared to today? Compared to a specific day as start of week?

Comment: I point it out myself. In general, I can choose any number of days I want.

Comment: Why don't you have `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format? Can you show us your `create table` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considered

> everyday for the last week, f.e. from 13th january 00:00 till 20th
>   january 00:00

and

> I point it out myself. In general, I can choose any number of days I
>   want.

I guess it works only as a filter so the task is "find users online everyday during selected interval

```
SELECT id,
       count(DISTINCT toDate(visiting_time)) AS number_of_days_visited
FROM user_visits
WHERE visiting_time BETWEEN '2001-01-13 00:00:00' AND '2001-01-20 00:00:00'
GROUP BY id
HAVING number_of_days_visited =
       round((toUInt32(toDateTime('2001-01-20 00:00:00')) - toUInt32(toDateTime('2001-01-13 00:00:00'))) / 60 / 60 / 24)
```

In HAVING I computed number of days from the WHERE filter.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work only if the `visiting_time` column format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`, otherwise the dates are not comparable:

```
SELECT t.id FROM (SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT substr(visiting_time, 1, 10)) AS counter From table1 WHERE ((visiting_time >= '2001-01-13 00:00' AND visiting_time < '2001-01-20 00:00')) GROUP BY id) AS t WHERE t.counter=7
```

Comment: It doesn't check every day, it returns id with at least one match.

Comment: I thought you wanted distinct ids. If a user is in the table every day do you want him multiple times?

Comment: I removed DISTINCT from the statement. See my edited answer.

Comment: No, DISTINCT doesn't matter. Your request returns users who have been at least once a week, I need those who were every day.

Comment: Ok then. I'll give it a try and come back later.